# What is Universe resource?

Tags: 13.10

I tried to install VLC, Chromium etc from Ubuntu Software Centre. It shows tht repository cant be read. They ask for server config and all. What is this Universe resource. Too much confused.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

The repository components are:

Main - Officially supported software.

Restricted - Supported software that is not available under a completely free license.

Universe - Community maintained software, i.e. not officially supported software.

Multiverse - Software that is not free.

Ubuntu will provide additional support for software that they officially support.  Furthermore, Ubuntu will assign people to actively fix bugs, issues, and other problems with programs in those repositories as they are found.  In the case above, Main and Restricted.  As for Universe, you will have to rely on the developers, who created the programs, and the users, like us, to fix bugs, to solve issues, and provide additional help.  Ubuntu "may" provide support for Universe software, but that is up to Ubuntu.